# incompatible types char and boolean

Tags: java

Im writing a code in which I am trying to compare two characters in a string. Originally I had this

```
    boolean doubleX(String str) {
    boolean n = false;
    if (str.length() < 2) {
        n = false;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            String sub = str.substring(0, 2);
            char a = sub.charAt(i);
            char b = sub.charAt(i + 1);

            if (a == b == 'x') {
                n = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

The error it gave me was "incomparable types: boolean and char". This is the line it had a problem with:

```
if (a == b == 'x')
```

so I changed it to

```
if (a=='x' && a == b)
```

The second way of writing it worked. How come I am able to use the second statement but not the first?
Thank you!

Comment: The first expression is parsed as `(a == b) == 'x'`, where `(a == b)` returns a `boolean`.

Comment: For your reading, I'd recommend you take a look at [operator precedence](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/).

Answer (score 1):

because the comparison can only be made between two elements, if you want to add an additional element you have to use the operators && or ||
For more information:

https://libguides.mit.edu/c.php?g=175963&p=1158594